# 1:1 correspondence of spiritual purity to spiritual impurity?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

I’ve always held the belief that the amount of spiritual purity in the world is equal to the amount of spiritual impurity. I think I heard this idea before, however, I do not know the source. My question is, if this idea is true, what is the earliest source that states this fact?

Comment: Ze Leumas Ze Asah Elokim?

Comment: Perhaps the 50 gates of tumah / 50 gates of kedusha?

Comment: I don't think that's true. Our task is to increase the purity and decrease the impurity.